# How can I change Asynchronous Task to Synchronous in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, asynchronous, synchronous

When I use this code i'm able to get the result

```
var photos = DataService.GetPhotos();
var groupedPhotos =
   from photo in photos
   orderby photo.TimeStamp
   group photo by photo.TimeStamp.ToString("y") into photosByMonth
   select new KeyedList<string, Photo>(photosByMonth);
GroupedPhotos = new List<KeyedList<string, Photo>>(groupedPhotos);
```

But at the same when i try to use this

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    var photos = DataService.GetPhotos();
    var groupedPhotos =
        from photo in photos
        orderby photo.TimeStamp
        group photo by photo.TimeStamp.ToString("y") into photosByMonth
        select new KeyedList<string, Photo>(photosByMonth);

    GroupedPhotos = new List<KeyedList<string, Photo>>(groupedPhotos);

});
```

I'm unable to get my result please suggest!!

Comment: DataService.GetPhotos(); is call asynchronous?

Comment: @Ritu Tyagi Do you mean you are unable to access GroupedPhotos from outside the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() method call?

Comment: yes @rikkit i want to acess GroupedPhotos by using the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() Method call.

Comment: GroupedPhotos looks like a property on a class. So Dispatcher.BeginInvoke shouldn't change anything, the property GroupedPhotos should still contain the results you want. The only difference is that it's running on a different thread - so you need to have some kind of signal to tell you when the results are ready. Does this make sense?

Comment: a) this code is taken from this:https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/PhotoHub-Windows-Phone-8-fd7a1093/ sample, would be nice to mention it
b) when you say 'i'm unable to get my result', what exactly do you mean?  I imagine this would be pretty slow but will eventually update the property GroupedPhotos, albeit on the main thread. So if you're trying to access it immediately after `BeginInvoke` then of course it's not set yet.